# Multiple sensors on an android application

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sensors, sensor-fusion

I am currently developing an android application that uses multiple sensors, I have used 
`mSensor= mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);` in `OnCreate` Method to get the sensor and `tv.setText("X: "+ sensorEvent.values[0] + ...);`in `onSensorChanged` method, to display the accelerometer values in a text view.

How can I add more sensors and display their values in the same way? 
How will the program know which sensor I am referring to when I say `sensorEvent.values[0]`?

Thank you for any help in advance,
Maja

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to check if the sensor values are of that type of sensor with the event.sensor.getType() method. So if you wanted to access both the Magnetometer and Accelerometer:

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager)   
getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
sensorAccelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
sensorMagnetic = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
            magnetic = event.values;
            tv.setText("X: "+ magnetic.values[0] + ...);
        }
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
            gravity = event.values;
            tv2.setText(X: " + gravity.values[0] + ...);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: What if all sensors changed at the same time? What will be the contents of event.values?

Comment: Each sensor will trigger a separate event callback. You will never need to worry about event.values containing other than the values of the sensor that made the callback.