# onAccuraryChanged() doesn't get called back with multiple sensor types

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm developing an application in which I require to know the accuracy of 2 sensor type's data, which are TYPE_ACCELEROMETER and TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD. I did registered the `SensorEventListener` to both sensor types as following:

```
     mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorEventListener,
                    mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
            mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorEventListener,
                    mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
```

Then in my listener, I did something like :

```
     @Override public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
         switch (sensor.getType()) {
            case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                if (i == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH) {
                   .....
                }
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                if (i == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_ACCURACY_HIGH) {
                   .....
                }
                break;
          }
      }
```

However for some reason, whenever it gets called back, the `sensor.getType()` is always `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`, I have never got another one.... Am I misusing this call back? Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
sensorManager = (SensorManager)
getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
sensorAccelerometer = 
sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
sensorMagnetic = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
          magnetic = event.values;
          tv.setText("X: "+ magnetic.values[0] + ...);
        }
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER){
          gravity = event.values;
          tv2.setText(X: " + gravity.values[0] + ...);
       }
    }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41860246/7092449

Maybe switch see only one Sensor and break another ;)

Comment: I actually can get both sensor's information in `onSensorChanged()` call back, just the `onAccuracyChanged` is problematic..